# Delegates, lambdas and Func

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, delegates

I have a case where I need to call several different web endpoints and need to do the same setup and tear down for every call.  I am trying to write a more generic method where I can pass in the method I want to execute along with the package to send to the endpoint and expect a string return.

---

From my code I can make this call:

```
var ret = WebServiceHandler.Execute(WebServiceHandler.LoadNewAsset(package));
```

---

The definition of Execute looks like:

```
internal static string Execute<T>(Func<T, string> executeThisAction)
{
    Func<T, string> resp;

    Setup();
    resp = executeThisAction;
    CleanUp();

    return resp.ToString();
}
```

---

This is one of the methods I want to execute:

```
internal static Func<CarsWS_AssetLoad, string> LoadNewAsset(AssetLoad package)
{
    string resp;
    try
    {
        // Make the web service call...
        var assetLoadReturn = _service.LoadNewAsset(new LoadNewAssetRequest {UserCredentialsHeader = _credentials, asset = package});

        // Evaluate results...
        if (assetLoadReturn.LoadNewAssetResult.responseType == "Success")
            resp = (result != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.asset.assetID))
                ? "Got assetID: " + result.asset.assetID
                : "No assetID returned.";
        else
            resp = result.responseDescription.Trim();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resp = "Error calling LoadNewAsset()." + Environment.NewLine + ex.GetFullMessage();
    }

    return resp;  // <== THIS IS NOT A VALID RETURN <== //
}
```

My brain is shutting off at this point.  How do I return the string back up the call stack correctly???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace:

```
internal static string Execute<T>(Func<T, string> executeThisAction)
```

with

```
internal static string Execute<T>(Func<T, string> executeThisAction, T argument)
```

then replace:

```
internal static Func<CarsWS_AssetLoad, string> LoadNewAsset(AssetLoad package)
```

with

```
internal static string LoadNewAsset(AssetLoad package)
```

then to call it:

```
var ret = WebServiceHandler.Execute(WebServiceHandler.LoadNewAsset, package);
```

Comment: I noticed that someone downvoted this. Is there a problem with the original solution or was the downvote purely for formatting? If it is purely for formatting I hope that this is not common practice for StackOverflow users.

Comment: When I posted the question, it was down voted within seconds.  I refreshed the page after posting and voila - a down vote.  No idea what is going on!  <grrr/>

Comment: Your changes work except when I step through the Execute method.  For some reason, the | resp = executeThisAction; | part is not actually executing.  It never hits the target method being passed in.

Comment: Never mind - I had the wrong internal definition on the return variable.  Working like a champ now!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in your `LoadNewAsset` method the `CarsWS_AssetLoad` class is actually the same as `AssetLoad` and it was just a editing issue with your question.

That being the case, I think this is what you want:

```
internal static string Execute<T>(Func<T, string> executeThisAction, AssetLoad package)
{
    string resp;

    Setup();
    resp = executeThisAction(package);
    CleanUp();

    return resp;
}

internal static Func<AssetLoad, string> LoadNewAsset()
{
    return package =>
    {
        string resp;

        var assetLoadReturn = _service.LoadNewAsset(new LoadNewAssetRequest {UserCredentialsHeader = _credentials, asset = package});

        if (assetLoadReturn.LoadNewAssetResult.responseType == "Success")
            resp = (result != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.asset.assetID))
                ? "Got assetID: " + result.asset.assetID
                : "No assetID returned.";
        else
            resp = result.responseDescription.Trim();

        return resp;
    };
}
```

The use of the variable `result` in the `LoadNewAsset` is a little confusing too. Did you mean to use `LoadNewAsset` instead?

The above code should be able to workable for you, but it's really not the right way to go about coding this.

I assume that the `Setup` & `CleanUp` code is all about instantiating the `_service` that you're calling?

So the key is to code it this way:

```
internal static string Execute<T>(Func<IAssetService, T, string> serviceCall, AssetLoad package)
{
    string resp;

    var service = Setup();
    resp = serviceCall(service, package);
    CleanUp(service);

    return resp;
}

internal static Func<IAssetService, AssetLoad, string> GetLoadNewAssetFunc()
{
    return (service, package) =>
    {
        string resp;

        var assetLoadReturn = service.LoadNewAsset(new LoadNewAssetRequest {UserCredentialsHeader = _credentials, asset = package});

        if (assetLoadReturn.LoadNewAssetResult.responseType == "Success")
            resp = (result != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.asset.assetID))
                ? "Got assetID: " + result.asset.assetID
                : "No assetID returned.";
        else
            resp = result.responseDescription.Trim();

        return resp;
    };
}
```

Ideally if you would bring the `Setup` & `CleanUp` code into the `Execute` method so that the only way to call the set-up and clean-up code is thru the `Execute` method.

Even better, if the service class implements `IDisposable` then your execute code would look like this:

```
internal static string Execute<T>(Func<IAssetService, T, string> serviceCall, AssetLoad package)
{
    using (var service = Setup())
    {
        return serviceCall(service, package);
    }
}
```

Let me know if I've missed anything.